# Los enlaces al chat en la página principal no conducen al chat del sitio

Tags: bug, estado-completado

Hay dos enlaces al chat de es.SO en la página principal: uno en el menú desplegable en la cabecera de la página...

[image]

...y otro a la derecha, justo encima de las preguntas populares:

[image]

Ninguno de estos enlaces está apuntando al [chat del sitio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6493/stackoverflow-en-espanol) sino que apuntan a la dirección genérica http://chat.stackexchange.com .

Comment: quizás no sea un bug, si no que la habitación tiene id diferentes y el que se esta creando ahora sera el oficial de la pagina y este pensado asi, pues el otro fue creado hace bastante tiempo cuando estaba en Commitment, pero solo es una opinión

Answer (score 4):

Son salas diferentes, la otra sala esta asociada a sitio de Area51, esta sala esta asociada al sitio StackOverflow en Español.

No digo que no puedan unirse/migrarse o vincularlo directo a la sala de Area51, pero creo que esta bien así, de este modo queda separado la conversación general sobre este sitio (para usuarios nuevos por ejemplo, en la sala de este sitio) de la conversación sobre el progreso de la propuesta "StackOverflow en Español" bajo el marco de Area51.

[image]